# Why isn't this plugin.yml working

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working for an own bukkit plugin. But when test it, there is an error "org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml" Here is the error:

```
[14:05:01 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\arena_v01.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:160) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:364) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:326) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:68) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:14) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:133) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token; found character      '\t' that cannot start any token
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:179) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:591) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:161) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:146) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:133) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:237) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:160) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:123) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:106) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:121) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:480) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:411) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile.<init>(PluginDescriptionFile.java:232) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:155) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
        ... 8 more
```

Here is my plugin.yml (the description is in german):

```
name: arenas
main: com.gmail.xxxxx.arenas.arenas
version: 0.01
commands:
    FP:
        description: gibt die anzahl an FP zurueck
        usage: /FP
        permission: <plugin name>
        permission-message: You don't have <permission>
    attack:
        description: Greift Verfluchte an
        usage: /attack
        permission: <plugin name>
        permission-message: You don't have <permission>
    change:
        description: Aendert den Charakter 0-Blitzgott, 1-Heiler, 2-Verflucher, 3-Beschwoerer, 4-Illusionsmeister, 5-Giftmischer, 6-Pfeilschiesser
        usage: /change [player] [newCharacterNumber]
        permission: <plugin name>.op
        permission-message: You don't have <permission>
    getCharacter:
        description: wer bist du
        usage: /getCharacter
        permission: <plugin name>
        permission-message: You don't have <permission>
    FPgive:
        description: gibt fp
        usage: /FPgive [player] [fp]
        permission: <plugin name>.op
        permission-message: You don't have <permission>
```

Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: can somebody help please

Comment: What do you think is causing the error?

Comment: I don't understand why people on this website downvote perfectly reasonable questions. Just because you can't answer a question, doesn't mean it's bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it out: I have to replace the tabs with spaces

Comment: Well, your yml is totally valid in the question, there is no tabs?

Comment: Really? But not in my plugin.yml file. Now it works.